# Is there a direct way to crop an irregular dimensioned / non rectangular object in image where background area should be transparent

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, polygon, crop

I am doing object detection which gives specific polygonal points which I want to crop out from the original image, but apart from the region of interest all the background should be transperent(not just black/white color obtained post bitwise_and operation from ROI). Want to know if it is possible to crop it in that way rather than tweaking the alpha value to decrease the opacity of the background.

Comment: Transparency can only be achieved using the alpha channel, cf. [Fred's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68292871/11089932) below.

Answer (score 1):

That can be done by making a white filled mask on a black background in Python/OpenCV using fillPoly() from your polygon points. Then put the mask into the alpha channel of the image.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread("efile.jpg")

points = np.array( [[ [693,67], [23,85], [62,924], [698,918] ]] )

# draw white filled polygon from points on black background as mask
mask = np.zeros_like(img)
cv2.fillPoly(mask, points, (255,255,255))
mask = mask[:,:,0]

# put mask into alpha channel of image
result = img.copy()
result = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
result[:,:,3] = mask

# write results
cv2.imwrite("efile_mask.jpg", mask)
cv2.imwrite("efile_transparent.png", result)

# display it
cv2.imshow("efile_mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("efile_transparent", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result:

[image]